# Does archiving in Xcode include external files?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I just finished an iPhone app and submitted it to the app store. Afterwards, I was cleaning up and realized that I hadn't copied one of the image assets into the project directory.

My question is whether or not that asset was included in the archive (and consequently, will it be included with the app when delivered through the App store?). This effects whether or not I resubmit to the app store (setting me back two days because of the new wait time).

Thanks!